# How to alter PHP information coming from mySQL before JSON_encode?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, d3.js

I'm have a live website that uses PHP and a mySQL database. I'm looking to use d3 to create a few visualizations. But I don't know how to alter the data as it is stored in the SQL database before directly encoding it in a JSON for d3. My PHP:

```
$activity_array = $array;
   while ($activity = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_all_activities)) {

   // $user_name = find_user_by_id($activity['user_id']);
   // echo $user_name['last_name'];

   $activity_array[] = $activity;
}
echo json_encode($activity_array);
```

However, due to how my mysql database is set up, users are set up as numbers, so that what I get back in the JSON looks like:

```
[{"id":"93","date":"2020-05-01","user_id":"37","user_notes":"This user has blah blah."},...]
```

When I use this JSON to generate a graph in d3, I want it to show the actual user's name, not "37". In the PHP code above I commented out the query I have to get the user's name from their user_id, but then I have no idea how to get that into my JSON.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can edit your SQL query to `JOIN` your `users` table without changing this PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify the appropriate entry in the `$activity` array with the username retrieved by the second query:

```
$activity_array = $array;
while ($activity = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_all_activities)) {

   $user_name = find_user_by_id($activity['user_id']);
   $activity['user_id'] = $user_name['last_name'];

   $activity_array[] = $activity;
}
echo json_encode($activity_array);
```

It would however probably be easier to modify the `$get_all_activities` query to `JOIN` to the `users` table and fetch the username in that query directly.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thank you!